# Algorithm to aggregate key-value pairs where keys contain numbers

Tags: algorithm, coldfusion, set-theory

I will try my best to give a complete problem definition. To illustrate the problem I will give an example later on in my question.
You might want to jump to the example first and read my problem definition afterwards.

**The problem**

I have got a map representing key value pairs. The keys may end with `-NUMBER` where `NUMBER` is an integer number. However there may also be keys not ending with a dash and a number.

The key prior to the leading `-NUMBER` may contain dashes as well.

There may be multiple keys starting with the same string and ending with different numbers.

There may also be multiple keys starting with different strings and also ending with numbers.

**General conditions**

1. All keys are unique
2. The map is not ordered
3. The order of the keys is random
4. It is safe to assume that all strings in the keys are upper case
5. If there is a key ending with a dash and a number `n` **greater** one it is guaranteed that that there are all keys starting with the same string and ending with all numbers `m` with 1 < `m` < `n` are present in the map.
6. It doesn't matter whether the original keys ending with numbers remain in the final set or not

**Focus for the solution**

The solution should not strictly focus on optimizing runtime or spacial complexity but rather readability and maintainability.
There are about 200 entries in the map at most and there no high traffic is expected on the application.

**Example**

Input:

```
{
    "FIRST-KEY"   = "FOO",
    "SECOND-KEY-3"= "BAZ",
    "THIRD-KEY-2" = "BAR",
    "SECOND-KEY-1"= "FOO",
    "SECOND-KEY-2"= "BAR",
    "THIRD-KEY-1" = "FOO"
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "FIRST-KEY" = "FOO",
    "SECOND-KEY"= ["FOO", "BAR", "BAZ"],
    "THIRD-KEY" = ["FOO", "BAR"]
}
```

or (if original keys remain in result):

```
{
    "FIRST-KEY"   = "FOO",
    "SECOND-KEY-3"= "BAZ",
    "THIRD-KEY-2" = "BAR",
    "SECOND-KEY-1"= "FOO",
    "SECOND-KEY-2"= "BAR",
    "THIRD-KEY-1" = "FOO",
    "FIRST-KEY"   = "FOO",
    "SECOND-KEY"  = ["FOO", "BAR", "BAZ"],
    "THIRD-KEY"   = ["FOO", "BAR"]
}
```

**Final notes**

My solution has to be implemented in ColdFusion.
The input which I have to refered to as map in the beginning of my question is called [struct](https://cfdocs.org/struct-functions) in ColdFusion land.

You can formulate your answer in ColdFusion (script syntax prefered) but you can also choose any other language you prefer (including pseudo code) as long as you don't use another language's standard library that i can't use in ColdFusion.

Comment: @Prune I thought about asking my question on cs.stackexchange.com however since my focus isn't on complexity but readability I decided upon asking over here. What exchange would you recommend? Lastly I'm not asking for homework. Thanks for the heads-up tho :)

Comment: Interesting question.  It does "read" like a homework assignment, but since you said it's not .. I'll give you the benefit of the doubt ;-)

Comment: I just tried practicing my problem formulation skills. Also as mentioned in my comment above I was planning to ask the question on cs.stackexchange first ;) To give a little more backstory the algorithm is needed to process responses from an ancient interface running on a raw tcp socket. The vendor thought it would be a great idea to not use REST but a proprietary crude protocol that doesn't support arrays in the first place for data exchange.

Comment: Well you might want to add those details to the question to stave off down/close votes ;-) because you definitely put a lot of thought into writing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the ColdFusion community on Slack we came up with a solution that meets my requirements:

```
data = data.reduce(function(acc, k, v) {
    var lastElement = listLast(k, '-');
    if(isNumeric(lastElement)) {
        var newKey = reReplace(k, '-\d+$', '');
        // init array if not initialized yet
        if(!acc.keyExists(newKey)) acc[newKey] = [];
        acc[newKey][lastElement] = v;
    }

    // may be put into an else block. This is only in here to attach the original keys in any case
    acc[k] = v;

    return acc;
}, {});
```

IMO it's very consice, compact and elegant. Moreover it's mostly self explanatory and can be understood intuitively.

The idea is, that the whole problem can be boiled down to a single [reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).
For each element we look at the last "segment" (seperated by `-`) and if it's numeric we can build the additoinal array for that key.

If anyone disagrees or has a better solution I would be more than happy to see it.

Lastly thanks for the effords [Ageax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8895292/ageax), Credits for the solution go to [rodel30](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288202/rodel30)

Comment: Very interesting!  I like several aspects of the new version. Especially the use of `reduce()` instead of a for-loop (I keep forgetting about the new enhancements). Though parts of it seem a little less intuitive to me, like the undeclared variable `s`? Which variable should contain the "expected" results? I ran the code in CF2018 and dumped all three variables (`data`, `acc` and `s`) and none of them contained result as described in the OP.  What am I overlooking?  :-)

Comment: Never mind, looks like it was just a typo. Fixed :-) Regarding `// may be omitted`, it doesn't look like that line can be omitted or some of the "flat" keys end up missing.

Comment: @Ageax sorry for the late response. `data` will contain the results since `data = data.reduce(...)` and reduce will return the accumulator after it's done reducing. Regarding the `// may be omitted` comment, i stated in my original question that this requirement is optional :)

Comment: Thanks. I later realized it was just the typo skewing the results ;-) Yep, you did, but omitting it [drops the key pair](https://trycf.com/gist/7f14b976029d5070c90b57f04d5f8415/acf2018?theme=monokai) `"FIRST-KEY" = "FOO"` (didn't think that was optional). Very nice solution though! :-)

Comment: @Ageax Oh you're right, if we want to omit the original key for the ones that include numerics you'd have to put it into an `else` so only one of both operations is done. My bad, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 4):

If all numbers `1 ... n` are guaranteed to be present, a simple approach is to just loop through all of the key names. For each key, use a regular expression to extract the "group" name (i.e. `FIRST-KEY`, `SECOND-KEY`, etc...) and the *optional* `-NUMBER` suffix.

```
results = {};

for (key in structKeyArray(yourStruct)) {

   keyGroup  = reReplaceNoCase(key, "(.+)-\d+$", "\1", "ALL");
   insertAt  = reReplaceNoCase(key, "[^\d+$]", "", "ALL");
   isSequence = insertAt > 0;

   // ....
```

If the number is > 0, set a boolean flag indicating the current item is part of a sequence of similar keys.  Then check whether you've processed the current "group" before. If not, initialize it with an empty array.

```
    if (isSequence && !results.keyExists( keyGroup )) {
        results[ keyGroup ] = [];
    }
```

Finally, store the current "value". If the current item is part of a sequence, insert the value into the existing array. (Since `-NUMBER` is sequential, and starts at `1`, it can be used as the array index, ensuring values are inserted in the correct order.) Otherwise, just store it as a simple value.

```
    if (isSequence) {
        results[ keyGroup ][ insertAt ] = yourStruct[ key ];
    }
    else {
        results[ keyGroup ] = yourStruct[ key ];
    }

 } // end loop
```